# Selecting first tag but not second

Tags: jquery

I have this html:

```
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
```

I would like to select only the first `<h4>` tag within all the `content` classes. So far I have:

```
$('.content h4').each(function(i, element){
    var test = $(this).text();
    console.log(test);
}
```

but this will give me all the `h4` tags. How can I target just the first ones?

Note: The HTML is a simplified version so can't guarantee that the h4 will always be the second and fourth tags in content.

Comment: Why has this question been down voted? I can remove if it's a duplicate, otherwise I think it's a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`:first-of-type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo) like following.

```
$('.content h4:first-of-type').each(function (i, element) {
    var test = $(this).text();
    console.log(test);
});
```

Live example:

```js
var matches = $(".content h4:first-of-type");
matches.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>No H4 in this one, as an example</p>
    <p>still testing</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I **totally** forgot `first-of-type`!

Comment: I've tried this too but still giving me all of the `h4`s so i must be doing something else wrong

Comment: @tommyd456: Must be, `:first-of-type` works, I've added a live example to Azim's answer.

Answer (score 0):

<s>There's no one selector that will do that</s> *(there is now for this specific situation, in CSS3; see [Azim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35539646/157247); the below is still true for the **general** case that isn't specific to a simple tag)*, you'll need a loop, e.g.:

```
var matches = $(".content").map(function() {
    return $(this).find("h4")[0];
});
```

That works by building a new jQuery object from the results of looping through the `.content` elements and returning their first `h4` element. (If they don't have an `h4`, the callback will return `undefined`, and jQuery will leave it out of the result.)

Live example:

```js
var matches = $(".content").map(function() {
  return $(this).find("h4")[0];
});
matches.css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>No H4 in this one, as an example</p>
    <p>still testing</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>testing</p>
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <p>still testing</p>
    <h4>Another title</h4>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".content").each(function() {
  $(this).find("h4").eq(0);
});
```

Check out the working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/JGQWmL)